# Pycaret - How to tune data preprocessing steps?

Tags: data-processing, hyperparameters, pycaret

It's easy to tune model hyperparameters in pycaret with `tune_model` but how are you supposed to tune the data preprocessing hyperparameters?

You need to call `setup` before you create a model but it is in `setup` where you define these values.

Let's say I want to compare the effects of standardizing my data vs. normalizing it. Is there a way to do this built into pycaret? I could write my own loops or processing pipelines... but that seems to against the low-code ethos of the library...